# entity framework decimal scale

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0.2, database first approach.  Currently in my database I have a field which is set to decimal(5,2).  When the entity framework model is generated I see the properties of the model also show the precision set to 5 and scale to 2 and type to decimal.  The generated class has it built as:

```
public Nullable<decimal> ContractorAmount { get; set; }
```

Whenever I try to read a value from it which has a ending 0, such as 233.10, it comes back from the context as 233.1.  the ending 0 missing, is there a way to correct this?  it works fine when the ending value is not 0.

Comment: How are you retrieving the value?

Comment: What is the difference in `233.10` and `233.1` ?? It is just for formatting purpose that you would need `0`s

Comment: .NET is truncating the trailing 0 off the end of the number to save space and improve readability. If you want to display it to 2 decimal places, there are `.ToString()` overloads that will give you what you want. The fact that the trailing zeroes are removed has nothing to do with your database, EF, or any other external framework. The language does that on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are confusing *storage format* and *presentation format*.

`decimal(5,2)` will guarantee that you have a decimal number with two decimals that will be exact.

When converting the data to string for displaying by default it omits any trailing decimal 0. If you want them written out all the time, you should use a formatting specifier to ensure that is done.

```
Decimal d = 0.1M;
Console.WriteLine(d);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.00"));
```

The first line will output `0.1`, the second will output `0.10`.

Comment: I would recommend using N2 instead of 0.00.

Comment: @Rand Could you explain why that would be a better approach?

Comment: @Calvedos N2 will display the number as specified in the culture for numbers, and 0.00 will simply add 0 at end. So for exmample the following number: ´Decimal d = 123456789.1M;´ will display as ´123456789.10´ with ´0.00´ but with N2 it will display as ´123.456.789.10´ or in my culture as ´123.456.789,10´ which is easier to read in my opinion.